# How to escape special characters in ansible jinja2 file

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I would like to use Ansible to template a BASH file.
But I have one line in my BASH to print array length:

```
if [ ${#my_array[@]} -gt 0 ]; then
```

Seems like Ansible has trouble handling this line, always returns an error:

```
ansible error template error while templating string missing end of comment tag
```

If I delete this line then the playbook can template the BASH successfully.
How do I escape special characters in ansible jinja2 file?
I am very new to Ansible, any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

I think I can use `{% raw %}`

```
{% raw %}
if [ ${#my_array[@]} -gt 0 ]; then
{% endraw %}
```

I am not sure if this is the best solution but at least it worked

Comment: Actually, this is the way to go. You could also use the copy module, but then other parts of the script wouldn't get templated.

Comment: it works for me. Thank you